# Handling a two-table join on values of two columns

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite, left-join, database-performance

I'm working on a comparison engine that takes rebates from a number of rebate sites, and racks and stacks them for particular stores.

I have an `idlinks` table that associates the rebate site's id for a store with a master store list:

```
idlinks (rebate_site_id      int,
         store_id_from_site  text,
         store_id_master     text)
```

I then compile rebates from all of the sites, for all of the stores, in a `rebates` table:

```
rebates (rebate_site_id      int,
         store_id_from_site  text,
         rebate_amount       text)
```

Since new stores and rebates come up all the time, I want to pick out the rebates that I haven't correlated to the master list yet.  For this I run a query:

```
select * from rebates
left join idlinks on (rebates.rebate_site_id = idlinks.rebate_site_id and
                      rebates.store_id_from_site = idlinks.store_id_from_site)
where (idlinks.rebate_site_id is null and idlinks.store_id_from_site is null)
```

This works, but it takes about 5 minutes for only about 30k rows in each table, which seems long.  I'm using sqlite3 3.7.4 in Python on a not-ancient Windows 7 machine.  My code:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('my.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('''<the SQL statement above>''')
conn.close()
```

I think comparing the two fields across the all of both tables is what is taking all the time.  If I could compare for only one particular rebate site at a time, it would be faster, I think.  Basically do this for each `rebate_site_id` individually, and combine:

```
idlinks_1:  select * from idlinks where rebate_site_id = 1
rebates_1:  select * from rebates where rebate_site_id = 1

unmatched_1 = select * from rebates_1
              left join idlinks_1
                  on rebates_1.store_id_from_site = idlinks_1.store_id_from_site
              where idlinks_1.store_id_from_site is null
```

The `idlinks_1` and `rebates_1` queries are fast.  I tested the `unmatched_1` query on a subset table for a particular rebate site, and it was quite a bit faster.

I tried doing this with a subquery, but it didn't improve the execution time:

```
select * from rebates
left join (select * from idlinks where idlinks.rebate_site_id = 1)
    on rebates.store_id_from_site = idlinks.store_id_from_site
where rebates.rebate_site_id = 1 and idlinks.store_id_from_site is null
```

Is there a way I can rewrite the query to only do the join on the parts of the table that are for one particular rebate site?  Or, alternatively, is there a way to feed in the results of the fast queries into another `execute` statement, and I can just loop through all of the `rebate_site_id`s?

Comment: Try to create indexes: `CREATE INDEX idlinks_i1 ON idlinks(rebate_site_id,store_id_from_site)` and `CREATE INDEX rebates_i1 ON rebates(rebate_site_id,store_id_from_site)`. I think this can speed up your first query.

Comment: @rims I think this would help a lot. The idea of a composite index occurred to me, but I didn't know it was this easy to implement. I thought I had to create it explicitly in my table. Would I use exactly the same query I started with, or do I need to refer to the indexes in the query?

Comment: @rims OMG the query executed on the whole thing in less than a second! Please make your comment an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX idlinks_i1 ON idlinks(rebate_site_id,store_id_from_site);
CREATE INDEX rebates_i1 ON rebates(rebate_site_id,store_id_from_site);
```

This will speed up your first query.

Comment: You nailed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just getting the null values, why do you need to join at all?

```
select * from rebates
where (rebates.rebate_site_id is null and rebates.store_id_from_site is null)
```

Comment: This doesn't refer to the other table, though?  I need to see if there's a record for the same pair in the `idlinks` table.  All of the records in `rebates` should have non-null values for these two fields (since I know the rebate site and the store I'm pulling from).

Comment: A row in idlinks where rebate_site_id is null and store_id_from_site is null? Sorry, I'm not getting it. Joining on nulls isn't a great idea - you generally want to join matching rows and the nulls are unknown, so you're getting a cross product by joining all the unknown rows in one table to all the unknown rows in another. Could you explain the data a little more, and the result you're trying to get?

Comment: Since it's a comparison, I need to key the ids from the rebate sites to a master list of stores, so I can compare apples to apples. (Each site does their ids differently.) That's the `idlinks` table, and I create it (part manually) as I go along. When a rebate site has a rebate for a new store (one that comes up in my `rebates` table when I compile each day), I haven't matched it to my master list. So, I find that out by seeing that I don't have a corresponding record in my `idlinks` table.

Comment: However ... what I really did need was a composite index. That's exactly what the rebate site / store pair is.  Adding those indices did the trick (see the comments on my question).